# Wie lautet das Gegenteil von "Muttersprachler"?

Tags: single-word-request

Wie der Titel schon sagt bin ich auf der Suche nach einem Wort, das das Gegenteil von `Muttersprachler` ausdrückt. Meine bisherigen Ideen sind:

- Nicht-Muttersprachler
- Fremdsprachler

Beides gefällt mir nicht. Gibt es Alternativen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Von den beiden Vorschlägen, gefällt mir **Nicht-Muttersprachler** bzw. **Nichtmuttersprachler** (siehe [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nichtmuttersprachler)-Link wie [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9788/5180) erwähnt) eindeutig besser. Bei **Fremdsprachler** ist die Bedeutung potenziell unklar - es könnten auch Personen gemeint sein, die besagte Sprache gar nicht sprechen, nicht nur solche, die die Sprache zwar sprechen, aber eine andere Muttersprache haben. Der Duden definiert [Fremdsprachler](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fremdsprachler) - für mich überraschend - als

> jemand, der eine oder mehrere fremde Sprachen beherrscht

Eine Alternative für ein einzelnes Wort fällt mir nicht ein. Ich würde je nach Kontext umschreiben, z.B. **Personen, deren Muttersprache nicht XY ist**.

**Personen nichtdeutscher Muttersprache** ist z.B. auch eine gängige Bezeichnung.

Answer (score 4):

Ich vote eindeutig für [Nichtmuttersprachler](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nichtmuttersprachler), der Lesbarkeitkeit zur Liebe eventuell auch Nicht-Muttersprachler; übrigens äquivalent zum *non-native speaker*.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde aber sagen, dass das Gegenteil von Muttersprachler Fremdsprachler ist.
Mit Nicht+X kannst Du behelfsweise ja fast zu allen Wörtern Gegenteile bilden!

Comment: Das stimmt zwar, aber nicht immer ist das so gebildete Wort gebräuchlich oder sinnvoll.